# jquery draggable - containment

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a little project I'm working on, and have an interesting containment issue using jquery's `draggable`:

Basically, I have two divs - a top & and a bottom. Then, I have a third div that is a .draggable({}) and can be dragged in order to resize the top and bottom div.

-- have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kpt2K/7/

The issue is, I'm not able to contain the dragging as I would like. In the fiddle above, I put orange `<span>`s where I'd like the containment to begin and end.

Interesting note: I tried doing something of the following:

```
$('#container').innerWrap('<div id='containmentBox' />');

var containerHeight = $('#container').height();

$('#containmentBox').css({'height': containerHeight - 45);
```

this made the containment work for the bottom, but not the top span. So, I think I'm stuck using `containment: [x1,y1,x2,y2]`, but haven't quite grasped how to use it.

Take a look at the fiddle, and let me know what you can come up with to constrain the draggable movement to inside the two orange spans.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [containment option](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) allows an array where to set the positions where to contain it. Try this:

```
var containmentTop = $("#stop-top").position().top;
var containmentBottom = $("#stop-bottom").position().top;

$('#bar').draggable({axis: 'y', containment : [0,containmentTop,0,containmentBottom] });
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kpt2K/11/)

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a `helper:` and this will allow you to add a `div` which you can dynamically set the size of prior the draggable action occurring. This allows you reference it in containment although it's not actually part of the page yet. If you use `start:`, this `div` won't be there by the time draggable function looks for containment element. You can clean up in the `stop:`

```
$(<<selector>>).draggable({
    helper: function (event, ui) {
        var target = $(this).clone();
        var oBody = $(document).find('body');
        var containmentDiv = $('<div id="div_containment"></div>');
        containmentDiv
            .css('top',calculatedTop)
            .css('left',calculatedLeft)
            .css('width',calculatedWidth)
            .css('height',calculatedHeight)
            .css('position','absolute');
        containmentDiv.appendTo(oBody);
            target.children('div').remove();
            target.css('background-color','#f00');
            return target;
        },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(document).filter('body').find('#div_containment').remove();
    },
    containment: "#div_containment"   //containment via selector
});
```

You can use a JavaScript object reference to set calculated values in `helper:` elsewhere

Comment: This works great.  I wanted to drag the original DOM object so I just had helper: return $(this), which did the job.

Comment: kindly share example of jsfiddle because it does not work in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can constrain the containment in a bounding-box delimited by the 2 stop elements :

```
var top = $("#stop-top").offset().top + $("#stop-top").height();
var bottom = $("#stop-bottom").offset().top - $("#bar").height();
$('#bar').draggable({axis: 'y', containment : [0, top, 10000, bottom] });
```

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Kpt2K/9/

Comment: kindly update jsfiddle example, it does not work properly dear. Thanks.

Comment: Seem to work well for me... Here, is another with CSS cleared a little bit: http://jsfiddle.net/t3x2h7f1/...

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly the documentation is thin - I had to do a lot of testing to figure it out.

My mistake was in thinking that the containment array defined a boundary within which the draggable element could move, defined as [x, y, width, height], but I've found that the containment array defines the upper left and lower right points that define the boundary defined as [x1, y1, x2, y2] that the contained elements ***origin*** can move within.

This makes sense in that the last two array elements are defined as x2 and y2 (point properties), not w and h (rectangle properties), but the documentation should be more specific as to exactly what these parameters mean in context to the contained element, and within what context (against the contained element's origin) and coordinate system (the contained element's).

Comment: This is the best answer. It is also worth to mention that the corrdinates (x1,y1,x2,y2) refer to offset coordinates of the helper.