# Stop dragging at a point

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am creating a cover image for my PHP project. I want to make it like Facebook That i can upload cover of size greater than the desired cover size then I want to drag the cover up-down-left-right to let user re position it and set according to him-self. At this movement I am able to drag photo but I want to stop dragging if the image ends. Like user is dragging the image to left then the image should automatically stop dragging if the end point of the div matched to the end point of div. I am not getting proper sentence to describe this. I am uploading a fiddle that will show what I am wanting I don't want to show white background (may this sentence explains the example).

Demo Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/keshu/HC927/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".cover_image" ).draggable();
});
```

Comment: May this post helps you :[jquery draggable containment][1]

Try to use this 
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075893/jquery-draggable-containment/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the [`containment`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) option and check to mantain the image inside its bounds, it allows you to:

> Constrains dragging to within the bounds of the specified element or
>   region.

**Multiple types supported:**

**Selector**: The draggable element will be contained to the bounding box of the first element found by the selector. If no element is found, no containment will be set.

**Element**: The draggable element will be contained to the bounding box of this element.
String: Possible values: "parent", "document", "window".

**Array**: An array defining a bounding box in the form [ x1, y1, x2, y2 ].

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".cover_image").draggable({
        containment: [
        $(window).width() - $(".cover_image").width(),
        $(window).height() - $(".cover_image").height(),
        0,
        0]
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8ZBPA/

Comment: @lrvin Dominin thnx buddy

Comment: @IrvinDominin I have similar problem. See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/3bc6mm7b/ I need to set containment for left and top borders only. Can you please make it more clear for me how to do that?