# jquery ui : drag image upwards and downwards : limit by pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an image and I have to move the image upwards and downwards, I am using jquery ui draggable containment option, but its not working as expected

```
<img style="margin-top:200px;" id='img' src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png' />

$( "#img" ).draggable({containment: [0, 100, 0, 100] });
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/m3e6V/3/

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075893/jquery-draggable-containment

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/maxwell2022/DerNa/161/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing with your code is defining a box to confine the image in, which spans from the top-left point (0,100) to the bottom-right point (0,100), so you're bassically not allowing the image to move after it jumps to (0,100).

The easiest way to do this is to define a parent element that is set in the size you want ( via CSS ) and define `axis: "y"` to make it only move vertically and `containment: "parent"` to keep it there.

So wrapping it up:

```
<div style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
  <img id="img" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png' />
</div>
```

And the JS

```
$( "#img" ).draggable({axis: "y", containment: "parent" });
```

Live demo : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hKzM/)

**UPDATE:** If you require the image to not start at the top of the element, you can adjust its position the same way that `.draggable()` does : add inline CSS for `position:relative; top: 100px;` to the image element.

Updated demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hKzM/1/)

Comment: but the image is not moving upwards, I want to move the image 100px upwards and 100px downwards

Comment: @DanielDzussa: adjust it via CSS then : [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hKzM/1/)

Comment: thanks but unfortunately I can't extend the parent. can u check this http://jsfiddle.net/Kpt2K/11/ ?

Comment: @DanielDzussa: it is unclear what you want - the blue horizontal line is currently contained between the top of the two orange boxes. What should it be contained to?

Comment: sorry I what I mean is, they have defined y1 and y2 in the code, I want to define y1 and y2 dynamically. so I need a solution that works with y1 and y2, thank you

Comment: @DanielDzussa: I don't see why it is not working, so I assume you misunderstand how element placement works. In your fiddle, the top of the moving element is contained with the top of the orange elements, which is the position you defined. I've replaced the orange elements with orange bars to make it clearer : http://jsfiddle.net/Q5tsx/ (only HTML/CSS changes)

Comment: thanks, but my question is, why I can't define y1 and y2 points in my page. what I want is, I want to move the image a specific px upwards and specific px downwards regardless the parent.